# Definition of lim inf of a sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I have two questions concerning [image]

1) Do I understand correctly that the union part does not change the subset that we get from the intersection part? I.e., the union says: give me those elements that belong to at least one set An. But since we have an intersection before, the union will just take all the elements obtained by the intersection since they'll all belong to all sets of An starting from a value m. Am I right?

2) Would it then be possible to define lim inf as follows: 
[image][image] for m in **N**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For (2), note that your right hand side seems to be a function of $m$ while your left hand side is not.  If $A_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ then the right hand side is $A_m$ while the left hand side is $A_1$

Comment: @Henry: well, all I changed was to take out the union sign which did not involve n either...

Comment: The union sign changed $m$ from a [free variable to a bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Henry pointed it out in the comments, the fact that $\cap_{n \geq m} A_n$ is dependent of $m$ and $\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n$ is a quite important problem.

An example : take $A_n=[0,n]$. $A_n$ is a striclty increasing sequence of sets which limit is $\mathbb{R}^+$, we have : $$\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n=\mathbb{R}^+.$$

But $\cap_{n \geq m} A_n= A_m=[0,m]$ -since the sequence is increasing strictly-, which is dependent of $m$, and will not be equal to $\mathbb{R}^+$ for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then if we take the union of those sets, $\cup_{m\in \mathbb{N}}[0, m]=\mathbb{R}^+$ and everything is fine.

In conclusion, you will not be able in this case to find a $m$ such that $$\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \cap_{n \geq m} A_n.$$
In other words : $\forall m \in \mathbb{N},\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n \neq \cap_{n \geq m} A_n$

Comment: I got a bit confused with your example. 1)Wouldn't lim (An)=R+ as n tends to infinity rather than lim inf(An)? I was expecting lim inf(An)=[0,1] similar to Henry's example. Should't it be that lim sup(An)=R+. Isn't inf supposed to give us a common subset for all sets which R+ hardly fulfills? 2)you're saying "[0,m] will not be equal to R+ for any m." Why? We're excluding a finite number of m's on the left but the m's go into infinity like n's do. Thank you in advance.  @nicomezi

Comment: 1) Being in $\liminf(A_n)$ means being in all $A_n$ but a finite number. In this example every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is in $A_n$ as soon as $n>x$. So $\liminf A_n=\mathbb{R}^+$. 2) You have to understand it that way : "for any fixed $m$, $[0,m]$ is not equal to $\mathbb{R}^+$". Then you cannot express the limit inferior by just an intersection. Indeed, the sequence is strictly increasing, so by taking the intersection of all the sets begining by the set $A_m$, you are just taking $A_m$.

Comment: And would lim sup (An) also be R+ as n tends to infinity? @nicomezi

Comment: Do the maths. $\limsup (A_n)=\cap_{m} \cup_{n \geq m} A_n=\cap_{m} \mathbb{R}^+=\mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 2):

To help with the existing answer and comments, sometimes simply writing out what the notation says is the easiest way to understand things.

$$ \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\;\bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} A_n \right) \;\; = \;\; \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) \; \cup \; \left(\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} A_n\right) \; \cup \;\left(\bigcap_{n=3}^{\infty} A_n\right) \; \cup \;\left(\bigcap_{n=4}^{\infty} A_n\right) \; \cup \; \cdots$$

**Thus, $\;x \in \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n \;$ if and only if**

$(x$ belongs to each $A_n)$

or

$(x$ belongs to each $A_n$ except perhaps $A_{1})$

or

($x$ belongs to each $A_n$ except perhaps $A_{1}, A_{2})$

or

($x$ belongs to each $A_n$ except perhaps $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3})$

or $\; \ldots$

**Therefore, $\;x \in \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n \;$ if and only if**

$x$ belongs to at least one of these parenthesed descriptions, OR if and only if $x$ belongs to each $A_n$ except perhaps some finitely many of the $A_n$'s.