# How to understand limit sup and limit inf?

Tags: limits

Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation of $\limsup  A_{n}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty }\bigcup_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{i}$ and $\liminf  A_{n}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty }\bigcap_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{i}$ (maybe using representations of Venn diagrams)?

Comment: Are you comfortable already with limsups and liminfs of sequences of numbers?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand that $\limsup  A_{n}$ means "infinitely many $A_{i}$'s occur" and $\liminf  A_{n}$ means "all except finitely many $A_{i}$'s occur". Is this correct? I also try to see if there is an intuitive way to understand this

Comment: @Noah Schweber (and cliu): While looking up something else, I came across my answer to [Definition of lim inf of a sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1908594/13130), which I'd completely forgotten that I'd written until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recall the intuitive meaning of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ for sequences of *numbers*. Basically, given a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which has no limit, we can still try to look at what its limit *should* be "from above" and "from below." So, for example, in the sequence $${1\over 2}, {2\over 3},{1\over 3}, {3\over 4}, {1\over 4}, {4\over 5}, {1\over 5},...$$ we basically have two well-behaved "parts:" one going up $${1\over 2}, {2\over 3}, {3\over 4}, ...$$ and one going down $${1\over 2}, {1\over 3}, {1\over 4},...$$ which suggest different limit-y values, namely $1$ and $0$ respectively. These are the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the sequence $\overline{a}$.

---

For sets, the picture is similar. Given a sequence of sets $\overline{A}=(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, it's natural to try to define the limit of the sequence $L$ by saying:

- $x\in L$ iff $x$ is "eventually always in" the $A_i$s.
- $x\not\in L$ iff $x$ is "eventually always out" of the $A_i$s.

But this only works if the sequence "settles" on every specific potential element: how are we to make sense of something like $$\{0\},\{1\},\{0\},\{1\},\{0\},\{1\},...?$$

Well, there are two natural ideas here:

- $0$ and $1$ each keep cropping up over and over, so the limit should be $\{0,1\}$.
- $0$ and $1$ each keep dropping out over and over, so the limit should be $\emptyset$.

**These are the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the sequence of sets, respectively.** This isn't immediately obvious from the definitions, but it is a good exercise.

---

Incidentally, we can link the two notions of $\limsup/\liminf$ for sequences of numbers and sequences of sets as follows:

Suppose I have a sequence of sets $\overline{A}=(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. If $x$ is a possible element of the domain, we can consider the function $$In_x(i)=\begin{cases}1 \mbox{ if } x\in A_i,\\0 \mbox{ if } x\not\in A_i\end{cases}.$$

*(If you're familiar with characteristic functions, you can think of this as a kind of dual: visualizing $\overline{A}$ as an array whose $n$th column is $A_n$, the characteristic functions of the $A_n$s focus on columns of the array while the $In_x$s look at rows. This may not be helpful, though, so ignore it if it's confusing.)*

The point is that we then have the following: $$x\in\limsup(A_n)\quad\iff\quad\limsup(In_x(n))=1$$ (and similarly for the $\liminf$s).

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! So another somewhat related question: if the goal is to reach convergence does our task then become parsing the sequence of sets to the two well-behaved parts (i.e., lim inf and lim sup)?

Comment: @cliu: Consider the case of a non-decreasing sequence of sets. It makes sense to call their union the limit of the sequence. And for a non-increasing sequence of sets, it makes sense to call their intersection the limit. For an arbitrary sequence of sets, one approach in defining what the limit is (there are nonequivalent ways of doing this; e.g. in a metric space we could consider the limit in the sense of the Hausdorff metric) is to consider "limits" of the associated sequences formed by taking the union (or intersection) of the finite initial segments of the sequence, **(continued)**

Comment: but modified in such a way that the resulting limit sets are unaffected by a change in any finitely many of the original sets (same as is the case with the limit of a sequence of real numbers). If you carefully look at what the union-intersection and intersection-union formulations of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ say, you'll see that they are designed to do this.